# I want to validate a button click in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

There is an input tag which gets some text and a button to submit the information. I want to make sure the user clicks button. This is not related to validating the input. Just want to make sure that if the user is viewing this page and has entered text then he must click the button before moving onto the next page.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="Search for a domain" name="page1.domainSearch" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" (ngModelChange)="func()" />
<button type="submit"  class="search" (click)="func()" [disabled]="!searchValue"></button>
```

I know i can add a boolean variable to this component and then pass the value of this variable to the component having the button to progress to next page as an input. But is there any way to make sure of this in the same component?

Comment: How does user move on to next page?

Comment: By clicking on another button which is part of another component.

Comment: I would put an onchange event on the input that disables the button leading to the next page and then re-enable it in the click handler for the text submit button

Comment: how about just having a boolean? make it true when user clicks the submit button. and disable the other button until this boolean is true!